# How to get file contents by inode in Bash?

Tags: bash, filesystems, inode

How can I retrieve file contents in Bash by knowing only the inode of the file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [this unixexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204724/174821):

> You cannot access files by inodes, because that would break access control via permissions. For example, if you don't have the permission to traverse a directory, then you can't access any of the files in that directory no matter what the permissions on the file are. If you could access a file by inode, that would bypass directory permissions.

There is some ways to get the path or name of a file through an inode number though, for example using [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find). Once you get one path to the file, you can use any of the regular tools.

`find` has an `inum` argument to look up files by inodes. Here is an example:

```bash
find -inum 1704744 -exec cat {} \;
```

This will print the content of the file with inode `1704744`, assuming it is located in the current directory or one of its children.

*Note*: `ls` also has a `-i` option to get the inode associated with files.

Answer (score 12):

Get inode with ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem:

```
inode=262552
device=/dev/sda1
sudo debugfs -R "ncheck $inode" $device 2>/dev/null
```

Output (example):

```
Inode   Pathname
262552  /var/log/syslog
```

To show content of file:

```
sudo debugfs -R "ncheck $inode" $device 2>/dev/null | awk '/[1-9]/ {print $2}' | xargs cat
```

Comment: debugfs also has a `cat` command that accepts an inode number and reads the corresponding file content: `debugfs -D -R 'cat <8>' /dev/sda3`. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92816/can-a-file-be-retrieved-by-its-inode#635441) for more.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun: Thanks for the hint. That makes it a little easier.

Answer (score 8):

If you have access to `find` with `find (GNU findutils)` and *not* the `POSIX find`, you can use its  `-inum` option for it,

```
-inum n
       File  has  inode  number  n.   It  is normally easier to use the 
       -samefile test instead
```

Just use it along with the `-exec` option and open the file using `cat`,

```
find . -inum 1346087 -exec cat {} \;
```

Assume `inode` value for my file `sample.txt` is as

```
ls -id sample.txt
1346087 sample.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

The portable but slow way is using the `find -inum ...`, for getting the filename for the given inode and in the next step use the found filename.

If you need just the `content` of the file (by the inode number), exists some file-system/OS specific solutions.

For the macOS it is simple as:

```
inode=48747714
eval "$(stat -s "/Volumes/volume_name")"
cat /.vol/$st_dev/$inode
```

E.g. In the OS X's HFS filesystem exists the pseudo directory `/.vol`, and you can use for accessing file contents by their inode number as:

```
/.vol/device_id/inode_number
```

the `device_id` is is obtainable from the `stat` for the given `volume_name` in the `/Volumes`, (check `ls /Volumes`).